# Convert HTML w/ Bootstrap CSS to inline CSS

Tags: html, css, html-email, inline-styles

I want to send nicer HTML emails. However, Outlook doesn't allow external CSS libraries to be used. How can I convert any HTML file that uses Bootstrap CSS into an HTML file with inline CSS?

I found Bootstrap Email (https://bootstrapemail.com/). This would be perfect, except it only supports Ruby. How can I achieve this in languages such as Python or Node.js?